# How is the TPM related to the CPU?

Tags: security, cpu, hardware, tpm

I'm confusing myself at the moment on how the CPU relates to the TPM.

When I tried learning about Apple's Enclave (TPM), the video I watched made it seem like the TPM is a separate processing unit connected to the CPU. As in the TPM itself is a microprocessor connected to the main processing unit.

However, when I tried to learn about ARM TrustZone TPM (found in Android based devices), the article I am reading made it seem like the TPM is within the CPU, not separate.  The article specifically states "ARM TrustZone Technology is a hardware-based solution embedded in the ARM processor cores that allows the cores to run two execution environments".

I am having a hard time finding the answer online. I just want to understand the data flow so I can better understand mobile based security options for applications.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the TPM as a specification that describes the inputs and outputs necessary for its operation. Theoretically you could implement this specification purely in software and remain compliant with it. You could also implement it as firmware running on another chip. However, the more removed from the host OS and other hardware the implementation is, the more secure it's considered -- as it makes it harder to compromise the secrets it holds -- so the so called "discrete implementation" is the preferred one, if it can be afforded.